# What is the archive format used by mongodump with "--archive" key?

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

Is there a way to extract data from that archive without mongorestore?

Comment: Duplicate of [what is mongodb archive format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56512192/what-is-mongodb-archive-format), which has a more thorough answer.

Comment: @DanDascalescu thanks for the useful link! A "duplicate" is usually called something  created later )

Comment: [The SE policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651/150034) on duplicates is based on [quality.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240431/150034).

Answer (score 15):

It's a kind of custom tar multiplexed archive where the only spec is the code : https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools-common/blob/7c66b71dc6036ef84bf3c2c93cf2e50f730853fc/archive/archive.go